# printerjob pagsetup dialog box always returns true JAVAFX Printing

Tags: java, javafx-8

```
private void pageSetup(Node node){
    Stage owner = new Stage(); 

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    if(job == null){
        return;
    }

    boolean proceed = job.showPageSetupDialog(owner);

    if(proceed == true){
        System.out.println("true");
        job.endJob();
        print(job,node);
    }else {
        System.out.println("false");
        job.cancelJob();
    }
}
```

always returns true even if dialog box is cancelled.

I think.

```
job.showPageSetupDialog(owner);
```

is the one acting strange.

I need help on how to cancel. Misleading button. java bug?

Comment: What is `job`? Please provide more information.

Comment: 'Stage owner = new Stage(); 
  
  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();'

Comment: Please edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was a java bug, it was fixed in version 8_152 and 9.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8067059

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've just edited my post. Try downloading the 8u152 java version (remember to change the java configuration in Eclipse's Menu and in "Run Configurations").

Comment: That will solve the problem too. In my case I can't upgrade because my company's systems and server are developed in Java 8 at this moment.